# Changing next and previous post link text

Tags: posts, theme-development, blog-page, codex

So I've been staring at the CodeX for about 10 minutes and can still not figure how to do this next and previous on a the post page.

So I've added `<?php next_post_link(); ?>` and `<?php next_previous_link(); ?>` to my page and works perfectly but I want it to say Next Post and Previous Post instead of the blog title. I've done this `<?php next_post_link('% &raquo; &raquo; ', '', 'yes'); ?>` copied and pasted it straight from the WordPress CodeX and not even that works it gives me the two arrows and a percentage sign.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm grateful for any help :)

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following for with Custom Text with Link.
The above given code by @TheDeadMedic works only with text but no link.

Code With Link and Custom Text like this:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link','Previous Post' ) ?>
<?php next_post_link( '%link','Next Post' ) ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will have to try this when I get back to my computer, thank you for the reply :)

Comment: Great works just fine, I wish they would mention this in the CodeX

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_post_link/